# Is switch/case okay to use with long scripts?

Tags: php

I was wondering if the following is okay:

So I have a bunch of different types of records I want to add and the forms for each type is different.  For example, Apple.php, Banana.php, Chocolate.php.  I don't want to create a different processing php file for each one and would like to have all the processing instructions on one file, add.php, instead of having addApple.php, addBanana.php, etc.

Is it okay to find the url and use a switch/case to run the instructions based on the url?

for example:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
switch (true) {
case (strstr($uri,'apple')):
  //20 lines of code to insert records
break;
case (strstr($uri,'banana')):
 //30 lines of code to insert records
break;
```

I am wondering because in a lot of the switch/case examples, it seems like it's often used to echo something.

Comment: Do your future self and others who might see this code a favor. Use the `if...elseif...elseif...else` construct rather than `switch(true)`.

Comment: @Chris Carson: Please explain why this is a favor.

Comment: @hakre: In this case, it's more concise, more readable, and less prone to error. Concision: each `if` or `elseif` or `else` block takes up the same amount of lines as a `case...break` block. You get rid of `switch` line and the `}` that ends the switch. Readability: each `if` condition is displayed in full right next to the `if` or `elseif` rather than referring back x number of lines to the `switch` parameter.  Less prone to error: Quick example... `true` can be interpreted as other types -- in this case I believe as the string "1". I don't think `switch` compares by strict equality.

Comment: @Chris Carson: concision must not mean more readable, especially if I see someone starting to count lines for a minor difference. I can understand what you aim for, but I was merely interested how come such an analysis so far w/o having the whole code at hand. And it could be considered noise in the context of this question. I think you did it with the best intentions anyway. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter in `$_GET` and use it together with `switch()` statement
It is better than lookup how the URL looks like and make decision.
That would be the case only if you can use `mod_rewrite` to call urls like this:
`/add/banana`,`/add/chocolate`

so it's better to do it like this:

call:  add.php?type=banana

php:

```
$param = $_GET['type'];
switch($param){
case.....
}
```

and about that you have a long code to work with, you should make some function which will work with datas abstractly like

```
function add_type($type = "defaulttype", $data = null){
    // do with data whatever you want, like creating save-arrays and querying db layer
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Long portions of code in each `case` will work, technically speaking ; but it'll lead to code that's hard to read/maintain.

I suppose an alternative could be to replace your 20-30 lines of code by function-calls ; this way :

- You'd have a `switch`/`case`s structure that is still readable : not too long,
- And you'd have a function for each case.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but I think it's better to use separate functions to save the records

```
$uri = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
switch (true) {
  case (strstr($uri,'apple')):
    saveApple();
    break;
  case (strstr($uri,'banana')):
    saveBanana();
    break;
}
```

This keeps your switch statement a lot shorter (and more readable). Also the different functions add to readability and maintainability.